# CameraOverlay goes to the background, and ActiveRegion is blank in front

Tags: .net, ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am using RedLaser and MonoTouch to develop a simple barcode scanning App. 
I have used the Sample code provided and I am able to deploy my code to the iphone and it scans Barcodes fine.

However, the camera view is not showing. The Active region is blank. Please see the image below 
[image]

When I run the sample it works fine. I am guessing it is something to do with wiring the Views and the Controllers

my Code is like this:

```
public partial class BarcodeScanModalController : CameraOverlayViewController
{
CAShapeLayer Rectanglelayer;
bool IsSilent;

public BarcodeScanModalController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle) 
{
}

public BarcodeScanModalController ()
{
}

internal void BeepOrVibrate ()
{
if (!IsSilent)
{
SystemSound.FromFile ("Sounds/beep.wav").PlayAlertSound ();
}
}

void setPortraitLayout ()
{
// Set portrait
ParentPicker.Orientation = UIImageOrientation.Up;
// Set the active scanning region for portrait mode
ParentPicker.ActiveRegion = new RectangleF (0, 100, 320, 250);
// Activate the new settings
ParentPicker.ResumeScanning ();
// Animate the UI changes
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation (0);
//this.View.Transform = transform;
UIView.BeginAnimations ("rotateToPortrait");
//UIView.SetAnimationDelegate = this;
UIView.SetAnimationCurve (UIViewAnimationCurve.Linear);
UIView.SetAnimationDuration (0.5f);

setActiveRegionRect ();
UIView.CommitAnimations (); // Animate!
}

CGPath newPathInRect (RectangleF rect)
{
CGPath path = new CGPath ();
path.AddRect (rect);
return path;
}
void setActiveRegionRect ()
{
Rectanglelayer.Frame = new RectangleF (    ParentPicker.ActiveRegion.X,
                                  ParentPicker.ActiveRegion.Y,
                                  ParentPicker.ActiveRegion.Width,
                                  ParentPicker.ActiveRegion.Height
);

CGPath path = newPathInRect (Rectanglelayer.Bounds);
Rectanglelayer.Path = path;
Rectanglelayer.SetNeedsLayout ();
}
```

Then I use this OverlayController like this:

```
public void ScanItemsButtonPressed (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (overlayController == null)
{
overlayController = new BarcodeScanModalController {  ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal};
}

if (overlayController.ParentPicker == null)
{
BarcodePickerController picker = new BarcodePickerController ();
picker.Overlay = overlayController;
picker.Delegate = new BarcodePickerDelegate (this);
picker.Orientation = UIImageOrientation.Up;
}
overlayController.ParentPicker.ScanUPCE = true;
overlayController.ParentPicker.ScanEAN8 = true;
overlayController.ParentPicker.ScanEAN13 = true;
// overlayController.ParentPicker.ScanSTICKY = false;
overlayController.ParentPicker.ScanQRCODE = false;
overlayController.ParentPicker.ScanCODE128 = true;
overlayController.ParentPicker.ScanCODE39 = true;
overlayController.ParentPicker.ScanITF = true;
// Data matrix decoding does not work very well so it is disabled for now
overlayController.ParentPicker.ScanDATAMATRIX = false;
// hide the status bar
UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden = true;

overlayController.Done += delegate {
DismissModalViewControllerAnimated (true);
} ;

this.PresentModalViewController (overlayController.ParentPicker, true);
}
```

I am using MonoTouch 6.0.8, RedLaser 3.4.0, and XCode 4.5.2
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be rather a simple issue.

The background Color and the ActiveRegion FillColor was a Full Color (not transparent), so it comes on top of the Camera View. I was able to resolve the issue by Setting the background of the Scanning View to No Color (Default), and setting the ActiveRegion to something transparent as below.

```
RectangleLayer.FillColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.2f).CGColor;
```